# Custom printers for protobuf in Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Im using protobuf 2.6.1 and I have a case where there are complex types such as UUID represented as two fixed64 fields, timestamps represented as longs etc which need to be printed in a more human readable way.

Im looking for extending the toString for all protobufs generically to convert the complex types to human readable types.

Is there such a way possible? If there isnt one for 2.6.1, is there any option in >= 3.0 ?

Comment: 3 allows you to output json which you could re-parse and customize maybe, but I'm not aware of toString customization. It's just not meant to be a nicely displayed thing. You can also put your own utility `String toString(Message input)` method with some code like `if (input instanceof SpecialMessage) return doThefancyDisplay(input) else return input.toString()` to customize where you need it

Comment: You can't do this without just writing your own method to convert the proto to a string. If you could change the behaviour of protos directly, it would break other code which relies upon the default format.

Comment: If you're just looking for some shorter output, you can use `TextFormat.shortDebugString(msg)` instead of `msg.toString()`